# How to sync finder folders into their respective albums in iPhoto?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, sync, finder, iphoto

Currently, I have set up in Firefox an add-on which when right clicked on an image toggles and saves this image to a specified folder. I use these folders as a reference library, now on 20 odd folders and increasing. Every day these folders get updated as I find more images.

I would like to have all of these folders I save to be ready on the iPad. This will help me immensely in my research work. Since iPad photos are synced from iPhoto, I want these 20 folders to be synced into their respective 'albums' and be synced/updated to iPhoto on the fly whenever I add a new image into the finder folders from Firefox.

How do I write an Applescript or set this up in Automator for each of the finder folders? I have no idea about script or how to use Automator.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be glad to know that this is pretty straightforward. (I'm using Mac OS 10.6.4 Snow Leopard with iPhoto '09 8.1.2.)

First, start Automator. A sheet will appear asking you to choose a template for your new Automator workflow; select "Folder Action" and click "Choose".

Next, you'll see the main Automator window.

[image: The main Automator window.]

In this window, choose the desired image folder from the drop-down labeled "Folder Action receives files and folders added to", near the top. In the leftmost list, select "Photos", and then double-click "Import Files into iPhoto" in the secondary list. In the newly-added action, select an iPhoto album from the second drop-down. (I've selected an album called "Skydiving" in my screenshot.)

Save the workflow with a name of your choosing, and you're done. Now whenever you add JPEG or TIFF images to your folder, iPhoto will open and import those images.

Unfortunately, I believe you'll have to create and save a separate Automator workflow for each folder you use, so that you can select the appropriate iPhoto album for each.

Comment: Many thanks Lawrence! You don't know how much this will help me in my work and also elevate the usefulness of the iPad. This seems so easy to do and now a bit embarrassed I did not explore more Automator's ease of use and power. Salute to you my friend :D

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. Don't forget to mark your question as answered!

Comment: Its done! And also I tried it out, its working perfectly now thanks to you Lawrence!

Comment: One thing I found is when I drop in images into one folder every few seconds, the system somehow doesn't copy these images into iPhoto. Automator seems a bit slow in reacting to images. So now I have to be more careful and still have to manually drag images into iPhoto where it decided not to do it automatically.

Comment: Broken since 10.*